# Пользовательский класс-ключ в контейнере Map

Tags: java, map, коллекции

Не пойму, почему не работает. Имеем код, в нем есть `Map`, в качестве ключа используем вот такого типа класс

```
class Key {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    Key(integer x, integer y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) return true;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (!(this.getClass() == obj.getClass())) return false;
        else {
            Key tmp = (Key) obj;
            return this.x == tmp.x && this.y == tmp.y ? true : false;
        }
    }
```

И пытаемся засунуть в `Map` значение `String` и вынуть его по ключу

```
void funk() {
    Map < Key, String > map = new HashMap < Key, String > ();
    map.put(new Key(1, 1), "Hello world");
    System.out.println(map.get(new Key(1, 1)));
}
```

Но получаем `null`. По идее `equals` переопределен и работает правильно, что не так?

И почему это работает корректно

```
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String s = "Key";
    map.put(s, "Hello world");
    String s1 = "Key";
    System.out.println(map.get(s1));
```

Comment: А что integer вы используете? Тоже своё что-то?

Comment: Это ошибка, там обычный int, не привык еще к яве

Answer (score 3):

Вам срочно необходимо переопределить `hashCode()`.
Кое-кто утверждает, что `hashCode()` в `Object` использует случайные числа и таким образом оба ваших эквивалентных ключа имеют разный hash.
Разный hash - разные объекты. До `equals()` дело даже не доходит.
Вот, кстати, статейка http://habrahabr.ru/post/168195/

Comment: спасибо за статью, разобрался

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста. А статья эта, если что, не моя:) Автору спасибо.